# TYPO3 - How is the content of typoscript setup handled?

Tags: typo3, typoscript

If i do a mysql-select within the ts-setup and call the result of this select in, lets say, three extensions placed on the same site, does that still mean, that this certain mysql-select is done exactly once within each call of the site?

If so, it would be smarter to do the mysql-select in the typoscript and give the result to the extensions, so i dont have to do the same mysql-select over and over for each extension again, right?

Or is the text from the typoscript handled another way?

Thanx in advance,
Jayden

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If that are exactly the same request, it will hopefully cached by mysql-query-cache. But, you are right, the request will be send three times.

If i understand you right, you think about doing sth. like:

```
lib.mySqlSelect = CONTENT
lib.mySqlSelect ...
plugin.tx_yourplugin.select.cObject < lib.mySqlSelect
```

That would result in three SQL Querys too.

But you could use an LOAD_REGISTER:

```
plugin.tx_yourplugin.select = {register:mySqlSelect}
plugin.tx_yourplugin.select.insertData = 1

page.1 = LOAD_REGISTER
page.1.mySqlSelect = CONTENT
page.1.mySqlSelect ...
```

Assuming "select" has stdWrap property.

If you are writing a new extension, you could use `$GLOBALS['TSFE']->register[$register] = $theValue;`

Comment: Thank you maholz, your answer has been greatly appreciated. I am using LOAD_REGISTER allready, but im still not very sure about this, as i dont really understand how load_register works. So did i understand you right, that even though each extension calls the values from TS for its own, that a DB-select placed in a LOAD_REGISTER is not repeated, once it has been done? its values are just safed and reused? Also, you are writing i could use "$GLOBALS['TSFE']->register[$register]" in a new extension, is there adifference between this and LOAD_REGISTER, as described above? Thanks very much, Jayden

Comment: have a look at http://api.typo3.org/typo3v4/current/html/class_8tslib__content__loadregister_8php_source.html

Comment: and http://api.typo3.org/typo3v4/current/html/class_8tslib__content__restoreregister_8php_source.html so, there is a difference. If someone request RESTORE_REGISTER too often.

Comment: yea, thanx, this may help me to understand load_register better, but is there a difference between $GLOBALS['TSFE']->register[$register] and the example above, or is it just a way to call the load_Register?

Comment: Could you give me an example, how to use $GLOBALS['TSFE']->register[$register] with a DB-select from Typoscript? Theres only very few articles online, handeling this topic...

Comment: $GLOBALS['TSFE']->register['tx_yourplugin'] = $data; it is just an global var!

Comment: So, in other words, safing the result from the db-select into $GLOBALS['TSFE']->register['tx_yourplugin'], so it is available in TS by "register:tx_yourplugin", and then i can give "register:tx_yourplugin" to other extensions, is that right? Thanks, Jayden

Comment: yes, that should work. But you should take care, that the plugin which writes the register is executed before the others.